# Ignore touch on absolute positioned view to allow scroll on underlying ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I have a View that is absolute positioned above a ScrollView:

[image]

I want to be able to scroll even though I start my touch inside the top view. I have tried setting `onStartShouldSetResponder` and `onMoveShouldSetResponder` on the View to `false` but it still doesnt allow me to scroll the underlying ScrollView. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If anyone is having this issue it is now possible to add `pointerEvents="none"` to the `View` you don't want to respond to touch. See the documentation [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#pointerevents).