# How to propagate touch event between absolute positioned siblings?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm working with **snackbar** and a **clickable layer**.

For example:
[image]

**Pressable Layer** and **Snackbar** are absolute positioned siblings, the code roughly looks like this:

```jsx
<>
  <PressableLayer></PressableLayer>
  <Snackbar></Snackbar>
</>
```

The problem is `<Snackbar>` is intercepting gestures, blocking `<PressableLayer>` from responding.

According to the [doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system#capture-shouldset-handlers), react-native's gesture respond system uses a bubbling pattern to decide who shall be responding. In this case, if `<Snackbar>` doesn't claim to be a responder, its parent get to respond, but I would like `<PressableLayer>` to respond instead.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340471/16596172)

Add `pointerEvents="none"` to the `<View>` inside `<Snackbar>` like this:

```jsx
return (<View pointerEvents="none"></View>)
```